# winAPI FindResource returns NULL only inside DLL

Tags: c++, winapi, dll, loadlibrary

I've stuck into a strange problem. The same code works perfect outside of dll but not working inside dll.

Code inside dll. Errors and nulls:

```
// 1813 here
    HRSRC hrsrc = FindResourceW(hInstance,
        MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_DIALOG1),
        RT_DIALOG);
    // NULL here.
    HGLOBAL hg = LoadResource(hInstance, hrsrc);
```

Outside dll, all fine:

```
// Pointer here, all fine
HRSRC hrsrc = FindResourceW(hInstance,
    MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_DIALOG1),
    RT_DIALOG);
// Pointer here.
HGLOBAL hg = LoadResource(hInstance, hrsrc);
```

The resource DOES exist inside the dll resources, I checked and even recreated my resource files. And it does compile in both cases, no `Symbol not resolved` errors.

And yes, I pass `hInstance` parameter to dll function. `double* arr = ShowXMinXMaxDialogDisableParent(hInst, hWnd, xMin, xMax);` It's not null (at least while debugging). I initialize `hInstance` inside WinMain function, so it's correct:

```
// main function
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
    HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow) {
    hInst = hInstance;
```

I have no ideas what's wrong. hInstance is wrong? Obvious, I checked it with debugger. No changes, the value is absolutely the same.

*Solution:*

Needed to use the DLL instance, not app instance. I can get it in [DllMain](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/desktop/aa370448) dll function.

Comment: Presumably the instance handle is wrong

Comment: *And it does compile in both cases*  -- That doesn't mean anything, except that there are no syntax errors in your code.

Comment: Since a DLL is a separate executable (even though it is a "library"), it has its own hinstance handle, separate from the app.  Did you retrieve the *DLL* instance handle?

Comment: Ok guys, you all were right. It's not a dll instance handle, it's an app instance handle. My problem was, I think that there are equal)))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are passing the wrong `HINSTANCE` to the [`FindResource()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-findresourcea) and [`LoadResource()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-loadresource) functions. You are passing the `HINSTANCE` from your `WinMain()` function, which is correct only for resources located in the EXE file.
You want to load resources from the DLL, so you must pass the `HINSTANCE` of the DLL, which you get in your [`DllMain()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dllmain) function instead.

Answer (score 4):

In the DLL, the `HMODULE` argument to `FindResource(hInst …)` should be the `hInstance` of the **DLL**, not of the `WinMain`. Use the value of the first argument to `DllMain()` and store that somewhere.

If I understand, you are using the `hInstance` of `WinMain` passed to the DLL?

Comment: Aah! **EylM** beat me to it by about 7 seconds! @Eylm - have an upvote!